# Creating field ID Primary Key auto increment in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How do i declare an id with primary key auto increment?

```
package com.ncf.globofly.models

data class Destination(
    var id: Int = 0, #PRIMAY KEY Auto Increment
    var Sequence: String? = null,
    var Description: String? = null,
    var Status: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Do you want to primary key auto increment for database?

Comment: yes, and in my Database.kt

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it seems that you haven't explained what database software you are using.  Thus, people trying to help you are left to guess what software to answer for.  Based on the answer, I'm assuming it's Room - you should edit that into your question, and probably add the [tag:android-room] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using annotation first add the dependencies for database and annotation processor after that

```
  data class Destination(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var Sequence: String? = null,
    var Description: String? = null,
    var Status: String? = null
)
```